# Read/fetch queries are not working as expected when we perform a deletion in cassandra

Tags: cassandra-3.0

can any one help here:

1. We have a keyspace with name **testkeyspace** in cassandra
2. In that keyspace we have a table with name **testevents** where the size of the table is **250GB**
3. here we want to delete 200 GB data from **testevents**
4. we executed a quey which does that
5. however we are are not able to see the **freespace** after deletion
6. after deletion we are facing issue while fetching(reading) the data
7. cassandra version: **Cassandra 3.11.2**

**Table Details:**

```
 CREATE TABLE testkeyspace.testevents (
    tenantid text,
    ts timestamp,
    sampleid text,
    additionalproperties map<text, text>,
    contentproperties frozen<contentproperties>,
    contextproperties frozen<contextproperties>,
    testeventname text,
    testeventtype text,
    time timeuuid,
    value int,
    PRIMARY KEY (tenantid, ts, sampleid)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC, sampleid DESC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 10000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

**Please suggest**

1. we expecting immediate freespace after deleting
2. Read queries should work with out any issue